# Camera Intent not working on lower android versions

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

On testing the camera intent class, my attempt to set the imageView in accordance with the photo clicked by the users **failed miserably(the imageView did not display the taken image) on devices lower than Android 3.0**. The class works fine in the latter Android devices.

Are there any changes required in this code so that devices lower than Android 3.0 can support this project too?

**Initial Definitions**

```
    private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 0;
    private Uri mUri;
    private Bitmap mPhoto;
```

**button.onClick Method:**

```
    Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "photo.jpg");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
    mUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    startActivityForResult(i, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

**finally the onActivityResult:**

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                getContentResolver().notifyChange(mUri, null);
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                try {
                    mPhoto = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, mUri);
                    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_holder)).setImageBitmap(mPhoto);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what "failed miserably" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare check out edit. sorry for being vague

Comment: Why aren't you just loading the image from the file?

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried that, that worked, now I am doing this.

Comment: its more of a practice rather than a formal project

Comment: Are you saving the "mUri" in your onSaveInstanceState and then restoring it?

Comment: @Sean no i dont think i am doing that. the code placed above covers up all that i am trying to do with the mUri

Comment: So try doing it. It might be possible that the Camera activity you are openeing is requiring a lot of resources, causing your own activity to be shut down and then restored upon Activityresult. Read about how to do it here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save the uri in onSaveInstanceState. As old device has low memory,when they start new app like camera they stop your application. After camera's activity is finished then it again recreate your activity from the saved state.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    if (mUri!= null) {

        outState.putString("cameraImageUri", mUri.toString());

    }

}
```

and in your onCreate do something like this

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) 
{
  mUri=Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("cameraImageUri"));       
}
```